# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linearmodels' のエラーメッセージを解決するには？

Tags: python

Pythonを始めたばかりの初心者です。データベースを取り込み、定点的に分析するツールを作りたく、調べながら、その雛形を作成に入っております。
詳しい人でしたら、すぐに原因がわかる内容かもしれませんが、お助けくださると感謝します。

#### これまでに試したこと

コードを実行しますと、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-da3982689c24> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 from statsmodels.api import add_constant
----> 3 from linearmodels.datasets import mroz
      4 #データの概要を表示する
      5 print(mroz.DESCR)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linearmodels'
```

#### 現状のコード

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
from linearmodels.datasets import mroz
#データの概要を表示する
print(mroz.DESCR)
data = mroz.load()
data = data.dropna()
data = add_constant(data, has_constant='add'
```

Comment: Anaconda環境だとしたらこちらかも。[conda-forge / packages / linearmodels 4.18](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/linearmodels) Anaconda環境でpipを使った時 [Error installing the linearmodels package on Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50414527/9014308)

Comment: 拙い質問を編集、改善頂きありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

指定したモジュール "linearmodels" がインストールされていないのが原因だと思われます。
以下の通り `pip` コマンドでインストールを行ってからプログラムを実行してみてください。

```
pip install linearmodels
```

**参考:**
[ModuleNotFoundError for module 'linearmodels' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64821596)

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！